# How to read mouse buttons from linux console using X10 mouse reporting?

Tags: linux, mouse, console

I'm trying to read mouse buttons from the console without success. According to man console_codes the Linux console has X10 mouse reporting. This means that after enabling it `(printf "\e[?9h")` pressed button + mouse position should be reported on stdin with:

```
\e[M b x y
```

where b is pressed button + 32 and  x, y are mouse coords.

No luck, this only works with xterm alikes. I'm not the only one, please see:

> http://myfreebsd.homeunix.net/freebsd/mouse_events_shell.html
>
> "...Surprisingly, since I read about mouse tracking in a Linux console_codes man page, these escape codes do not work in any Linux console that I have tried..."

Has anybody tried this with success? Is this a bug?

Comment: `stdin`? You mean `stdout`.

Comment: Nope, it's stdin, console driver injects \e[M b x y to stdin head, so as to be read by the application. That's how mouse reporting works.